# Contour for $\mathcal{L} f(t) g(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F(\sigma) G(s-\sigma) d\sigma$

Tags: laplace-transform

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems), The formua for Laplace Transform of two functions is $$\mathcal{L} f(t) g(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F(\sigma) G(s-\sigma) d\sigma$$

where, vertical line at $c$ is chosen to be in ROC of $F$

**2 questions**:

1. Why is the emphasis only on $F$ for choosing $c$? What about $G$? I couldn't find any derivation of this result on internet (including in the book that Wikipedia cites for this result). Either can someone please explain/derive this or point me to a derivation online?
2. If we have F=G and they have ROC of the form $Re(p) > 0$ (where $p$
       is the complex variable of LT) $\color{blue}{AND}$ F=G has a branch point at $p=0$,
       after flipping the usual branch cut for $F$ (negative real
       axis) and similarly for $G(s-\sigma)$, I am left with a combined branch cut
       between $[0,Re(s)]$.In this case, can I choose $c$, such that $c >
       Re(s)$, such that this contour is on the right of the modified
       branch cut? Or am I not allowed to form this kind of branch cut as
       LT is supposed to be analytic in its ROC?

Comment: It depends on what you assume about $f,g,F,G$. Do you know how regularization helps for the Fourier transform (of distributions), that is replacing $f$ by $f_n = f\ast \frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-n^2 x^2/2}$ ? If $f$ is bounded then $f_n$ is Schwartz so that everything converges absolutely and we can change the order of integration in $\frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^2}\int_{b-i\infty}^{b+i\infty}  \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F_n(z) G_n(s-z) dz e^{sx}ds$ obtaining that it is $=f_n(x) g_n(x)$. Finally it suffices to check what happens when letting $n\to \infty$.

Comment: This is unfamiliar area for me. While I try to understand your comment regarding my question #1, do you have any comments on my second question?

Comment: (I meant $f_n(x)e^{-\sigma x}$ is Schwartz). Is it clear to you that when $F,G$ are $L^1$ on vertical lines then the result is easy by changing the order of integration in $\frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^2}\int_{b-i\infty}^{b+i\infty}  \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F(z) G(s-z) dz e^{sx}ds$ ? The regularization approximates $f,g$ with some functions whose Laplace transform are $L^1$ on vertical lines.

Comment: I guess I just don't have the mathematical background to understand your comments. I will do more homework before I return with more questions. Thanks for your comments.